# .Hover function isn't working

Tags: jquery, css

On my site I have multiple pictures, upon hovering on a picture jquery ought to make the image title visible via toggleClass + css, but no such luck. I'm pretty sure the problem lies in the jquery, but after numerous attempts tinkering with `$this`, switching `.parents` to `.closest` to `.parentsUntil` to etc, I've decided to seek assistance, please help I'll definitely appreciate it.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ujb1evwz/) illustrating my the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just fixed your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ujb1evwz/3/)

There were some issues - jquery was not included, the class `imghover` was missing the closing `}`, and I've adjusted the jquery select to

```
$(this).parents('div').find("h2").toggleClass('imghover');
```

As I noticed that in your Fiddle the class `imghover` ends with `tr`, it looks like not the complete css was copied into the original Fiddle. In first Fiddle above I've just removed this `tr` and added the missing `}` to close the class, so some of your intended css, e.g. `transition`, could be  missing. With just adding a transition - as I'd guess that something like this was intended - the adjusted second [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ujb1evwz/10/) looks better. I also removed the `var $this = $(this);` as it's not needed anymore.

Comment: I'm running into a problem, your answer definitely helps, but I'm trying to incorporate this for multiple images, where only one title appears at a time, but instead it shows all titles at once. Here's the site http://www.hitechwolf.com/wolfden/#, please help.

Comment: @Bakajuice No problem, I'm already checking the site. Problem is just that example fiddles tend to only demonstrate a functionality and have to be adjusted a bit for real settings. Just found the image_title.js with the imageHover() function that causes the problem.

Comment: @Bakajuice Can you just test if it works if you change `$(this).parents('div').find("h2").toggleClass('imghover');` into `$(this).closest('div').find("h2").toggleClass('imghover');` ? This could already fix it. `parents()` select all parent divs, `closest()` only the closest parent.

Comment: implemented above and it works perfectly thank you so much, I tinkered with the css media queries and that screwed it up, thanks again XD

Comment: @Bakajuice Glad to read that you were able to get it fixed, so you don't want to have it on desktop as I just noticed that it works when I resize the screen. Was about to paste some more code as I thought it could be an issue with drupal attaching the function. And don't mind, glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1):

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ujb1evwz/9/)

**Changed CSS**

```
.imghover {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(50px);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-style: italic;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

.imgtitle {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
    width: 296px;
    background-color: rgba(75, 85, 90, .95);
    border: black solid 2px;
    padding: 1.5%% 0 1.5% 0;
    border-radius: 7.5px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #000;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

There are two points you need pay attention:

1. if you use **transform**, use the **transition** can make the transform more fluently. In the case, I change the class **.imghover**.
2. when your cursor hover the img, the **panda** will display. But when you hover the **panda**, the text will shake. So, I add an attribute `pointer-events:none`. The reason of shake is `.imgtitle` node is not a child of the img.

At last, when you hover the img, the transition is comfortable.

Comment: thank you the use of pointer-events removes the glitchy effect, nice added bonus I appreciate it :D